# Use common source folder for several projects, and avoid absolute paths

Tags: java, eclipse, classpath, relative-path

I need to have one lib-project (myLib), and several apps projects that should use source from myLib. I have troubles with configuring Eclipse.

Desired projects tree is something like that:

```
myProject
   /src
      ..some files..
   /bin

myLib
   /src
      ..some files..
   /bin
```

Now i am trying to configure `myProject`'s classpath, to make it use source from `myLib/src`.

If i add link source using Eclipse's GUI (**UPD:** I added link to the source folder this way: *right-click on the project* -> *Build path* -> *Configure build path* -> *go to "Source" tab* -> *press button "Link Source..."* -> *specify path to the `myLib/src` and folder name: "`lib_src`"*), then i got absolute path to `myLib/src`, i.e. the following:

**`myProject/.classpath`**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<classpath>
    <classpathentry kind="src" path="src"/>
    <classpathentry kind="src" path="lib_src"/>
    <classpathentry kind="con" path="org.eclipse.jdt.launching.JRE_CONTAINER"/>
    <classpathentry kind="output" path="bin"/>
</classpath>
```

**`myProject/.project`**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<projectDescription>
    <name>data_manager__gui</name>
    <comment></comment>
    <projects>
    </projects>
    <buildSpec>
        <buildCommand>
            <name>org.eclipse.jdt.core.javabuilder</name>
            <arguments>
            </arguments>
        </buildCommand>
    </buildSpec>
    <natures>
        <nature>org.eclipse.jdt.core.javanature</nature>
    </natures>
    <linkedResources>
        <link>
            <name>lib_src</name>
            <type>2</type>
            <location>/HERE/IS/FULL/PATH/TO/myLib/src</location>
        </link>
    </linkedResources>
</projectDescription>
```

As I already said, I need to avoid absolute paths. So, I need path `myLib/src` to be specified like that: `../myLib/src`

Then i tried to specify path to myLib/src manually, but if I add in **`.classpath`** the line like that:

```
<classpathentry kind="src" path="../myLib/src"/>
```

Then Eclipse thinks that .classpath is totally broken, and reset it to the following blank default:

```
<classpath>
    <classpathentry kind="src" path=""/>
    <classpathentry kind="output" path="bin"/>
</classpath>
```

Then I tried to change path in the **`.project`** file, but it seems like relative paths are totally not supported in **`.project`** file: Eclipse can't find my `myLib/src`, I tried many variants.

How to achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am not sure how you added the project reference, but in my case, the path is relative.

This is the `.classpath` of a project called `Adarsh` which references another Java project called `raroscope`.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<classpath>
    <classpathentry kind="src" path="src"/>
    <classpathentry kind="con" path="org.eclipse.jdt.launching.JRE_CONTAINER/org.eclipse.jdt.internal.debug.ui.launcher.StandardVMType/JavaSE-1.6"/>
    <classpathentry combineaccessrules="false" kind="src" path="/raroscope"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="geocoder-java-0.9.jar" sourcepath="geocoder-java-0.9-sources.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="commons-logging.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="gson-2.1.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="commons-lang.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="output" path="bin"/>
</classpath>
```

You should be right-clicking on your project `myProject`, select Java Build Path > Projects and add `myLib` (`raroscope` here) as is shown below.

[image]

Comment: Thanks, your solution works in my particular case, but anyway i tried to find the way to specify common source folder, even if this folder is outside any projects. And currently your path "/raroscope" is workspace-dependent: to make it work, you must have "raroscope" project in your workspace. It is definitely better than plain absolute paths, but i am still trying to find the way to specify path like `../myLib/src`. But, thanks again, right now your solution is acceptable for me.

Comment: By the way, I updated my question: I specified the way i added source.

Comment: Glad it helped. You might also want to explore how to create User Variables in Eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

Replace the path to your linked resource in your .project file with this:

```
<linkedResources>
    <link>
        <name>lib_src</name>
        <type>2</type>
        <locationURI>PARENT-1-PROJECT_LOC/myLib/src</locationURI>
    </link>
</linkedResources>
```

It's the `PARENT-1` modifier that causes the Eclipse to look one directory up from the project directory path for your library directory.